# How to tell yum I've moved countries?

Tags: centos, yum

I run a centos7 in a virtual machine on my laptop. I was working abroad for a month, and `yum` figured that out and changed the repositories that it checks (I don't know how that happened! Maybe I upgraded yum and don't remember?). Now I'm back, but `yum` still wants to download things from the other side of the world. How do I change it back? Will it happen automatically after a few slow downloads or do I need to do so manually?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used CentOS, but I've had a bit of a look around Google, and it seems to change enable/disable repositories, you should go to the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory, open the `.repo` files associated with the country that `Yum` is trying to download from, and set `enabled=0`.

Presumably, you will also want to find the repository associated with the country that you're currently in and make sure it's set to `enabled=1`.

(Here's my source material: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-maintenance.html)

As I said, I've never used CentOS or Yum, but are you sure it actually changed repositories?  In my experience with other distributions, there's a mirror list that takes care of where (geographically) you're served from.  For example, in Arch there's the `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`, and you un-comment the mirror servers that you want to use.  I would have guessed CentOS did something similar.

Comment: It definitely changed repos! yum prints which URLs it's using, the download times are quite a bit longer, and sometimes even times out.

Comment: Well, if what I suggested in my answer doesn't work, let me know and I'll do some more digging (although there's only so much I can do without actually setting CentOS up myself).

Comment: In my install, I don't see any .repo directories in /etc/yum.repos.d/. However, from your link, I did start looking around in /var/cache/yum and saw that it had some bad cached timings for repos. I remove those files and when I ran yum again, it said it was 'Determining fastest mirrors', but then all the mirrors it determined were still on the other side of the world. Somehow it seems to have limited itself to testing hosts there.

Comment: Interesting...  What version of CentOS are you using, and what is your computer's architecture?  If you know that, you can go to http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os (replace the environment variables as appropriate) and look at the public mirrorlist there.  That might give some clues as to what's going on.  There may be a way to grab a specific mirror from the list, but I'd have to think on it for a while.

Comment: It's centos7 running in a x86_64 virtual machine. I can see that mirror list, but it's interesting that even after deleting mirrorlist.txt from all the cache subdirectories and timedhosts.txt, it is still picking up hosts there.